# how to malloc a struct in system call

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

```
struct test{
    /*...*/
}

asmlinkage syscall(){
    struct test *t;
    t = (struct test *)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    //...
}
```

During I compiled whole kernel the follow error showing.

***implicit declaration of function 'malloc'***

Seems I can't include *stdlib.h*, but if I don't use *malloc*, the *t* pointer will be *NULL*.

That cause ***unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at (null)***

How to assign a pointer to *t*?

Comment: There is no `malloc()` in kernel but you can use `kmalloc()/kzalloc()` instead.  Also type cast of pointer returning from `kmalloc()/malloc()` is unnecessary in gcc. It's safe to do just  `t = kmalloc(sizeof(something), GFP_XXX)`.

Answer (score -1):

this assign a pointer to pointer type
    struct test *t;

use follow code

```
struct test t;
```

done

Comment: There is no pointer here. So instead of dynamic allocation you went for static allocation.